# Is this normal? When booting from live usb install, initram error and stdin invalid argument

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, error-handling

Im really struggling to install a system that boots properly once installed.

During live usb booting i get this:
[Errors on bootup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lfg2.jpg)

My live usb booting starts with initramfs failure error then stdin invalid argument just before checking system integrity,  it shows up twice.  See picture for detail.  Help is much appreciated.

I read somewhere that very fast hardware can cause issues. Is this the case here? I have new generation ryzen 64gb 3600mhz ram and using an ssd

Once i install from this live usb, i have graphics corruption upon loading of fresh install, i have to boot in recovery mode and then install nvidia drivers which seems to fix the problem of corrupt graphics. However after a while the booting doesnt happen successfully and i get an error to do with "you must load kernel first".and hd2 gpt not found.

Is my SSD dead perhaps?

Im thinking my fresh system install doesn't work due to the earlier mentioned errors with live usb...
More details to follow...

Comment: Cannot upload second picture due to not having 10 reputation!

Comment: I also had the "initramfs unpacking failed" thing both on the **20.04.1** USB live image and afterwards on the installed OS too. (On the installed OS it's an easy fix). I also had to do like at least four attempts on a complete formatting + install until it finally booted. (At the time I thought that I made complications for myself with legacy boot vs the EFI partition, and even ended up reinstalling grub.) I'm on this forum a bit longer than 1 month, and have seen a few threads since with "fresh install does not boot".

Comment: "Is my SSD dead perhaps?" You can use the live USB to run `fsck` on the unmounted `/` partition of the SSD, to find out.